# Integrating Cocoapods with large existing Xcode Workspace

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode-project, xcode-workspace

I have recently been working with Cocoapods on my own projects, and would like to incorporate a couple of pods into a project at work. The problem is that our code consists of close to 20 projects stored inside a large workspace, sorted into folders. The structure of the projects is

- Workspace

  - Apps (Folder)

    - Project 1
    - Project 2
    - etc...
  - Modules

    - More Projects
    - etc
  - Base Components

    - Even More Projects
    - etc

I am unsure how to write a podfile that would link a pod (RETableView in this case) against an app without disturbing the existing structure of the workspace? Is this even possible? If it isn't possible to incorporate cocoapods without changing the existing workspace, is it possible to set up cocoapods to compile pods as standalone libraries that I could incorporate into our project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CocoaPods 1.x you can use `:integrate_targets => false` in your Podfile like this:

```
install! :integrate_targets => false
```

You can find the documentation for this [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#install_bang)

Previously (for older CocoaPods versions):

After creating your `Podfile` use `pod install --no-integrate` documented [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_install). This will create the `Pods` project that you can then include in your workspace. Please make sure everything in your project is checked into your version control system first just in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: How to create the Podfile for existing project? Is it "pod init" in the project directory?

Comment: If you already have a project you can just create a `Podfile` with any text editor. `pod init foo.xcodeproj` would work as well.

Comment: There is no --no-integrate option in the linked documentation

Comment: I've updated this answer to reflect the newer versions of CocoaPods